# AS3. Store Array in Local SQL Database

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

I am developing an application in Adobe Flash Builder 4.6 (AIR APP) in which a user fills forms and stores data like name, phone, address (along with some report data) in Local SQL Database.
My coding is all Okay but have a just one problem. Along with data, there is an array which I am trying to store on Local SQL Database, but my all attempts have failed. 
I store array in `text` datatype in database and when I access the stored array it give an error.
`Cannot convert "[object Object]" to Array`.
I dont know what is the problem.
Please Help ... Thanks.

I use array with nested array like..
My array is

```
var ar:Array=["report_name", {label: report_label, number: 5}, [{label: Label1, data: Data1}, {label: Label2, data: Data2}, {label: Label3, data: Data3}]];
```

Now I store this array in database like.

```
sqlstatement.text ="INSERT INTO table (id, data) VALUES ('', '"+ar+"')";
```

In this statement data has `TEXT` datatype.
Now when I access it like

```
var array:Array = [];
array = Array(sqlstatement.getResult().data[0].data;
```

It give coercion error.

Comment: Not enough information. Show us how you store and retrieve the data that you have issues with.

Comment: Friend I have edited my question. Please help.

Comment: @MSJuGnu Please respect those people who may be willing to help you and format your code as a code, not as an unreadable mess of a text.

Comment: I suggest you to user SharedObjects for user's local data: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sharedobject/

But if you insist to user SQL data base, pars your received data from SQK ( the line that caused the Error ) with **JSON.stringify(receivedObject)** to get understand what the receivedObjec model is.

Comment: Bro. SharedObject is not a secure place for data storage. And I dont know the use of json. Please if you elaborate your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the result you get because SQL query is a basically a string, so it is equal to

```
"INSERT INTO table (id, data) VALUES ('', '" + ar.toString() + "')"
```

where you lose all generic objects **{...}** and the data structure.

**[MESepehr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2286503/mesepehr)** is absolutely correct, what you need is **[JSON](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html#parse())** data format, which will work fine for you as long, as you keep only **Number**s, **int**s, **String**s, **Boolean**s, **Array**s, **Object**s and **null**s there.

Then, it is as easy as the following.

Store:

```
sqlstatement.text = "INSERT INTO table (id, data) VALUES ('', '" + JSON.stringify(ar) + "')";
```

Restore:

```
var array:Array = JSON.parse(sqlstatement.getResult().data[0].data) as Array;
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect :) 
Thanks a lot...
Actually, @MESepehr give the same answer in comments but I didn't understand, So thanks for explanation. It is working fine.